# MATCH based on sum of common node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need help figuring out a MATCH statement.

My data model is as follows:

```
(a:musician {name}) //individual musicians
(b:jamSession {date, durationInHours}) //the date and length of jam sessions where 2 or more musicians participated together
```

and the relation

```
[r:PLAYED]
```

I've already figured out how to find all of the jam sessions a specific musician played at:

```
MATCH (a:musician {name:"Joe Smith"})-[r:PLAYED]->(b:jamSession) RETURN a.name, b.date
```

and all of the musicians a specific musician played with

```
MATCH (a:musician {name:"Joe Smith"})-[r:PLAYED]->(b:jamSession)<-[r2:PLAYED]-(c:musician) RETURN c.name
```

But how do I get only the musicians that Joe Smith has played with were the sum total time of their common jam sessions was >=100 hours and what date the pair of musicians meet the 100 hour milestone?

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you (assuming `b.date` is suitable for sorting):

```
MATCH (a:musician)-[:PLAYED]->(b:jamSession)<-[:PLAYED]-(c:musician)
WHERE a.name = "Joe Smith"
WITH a, c, b ORDER BY b.date
WITH a, c,
  REDUCE(s = {sum: 0}, x IN COLLECT(b) |
    CASE WHEN s.date IS NULL AND x.durationInHours + s.sum >= 100
      THEN {sum: s.sum + x.durationInHours, date: x.date}
      ELSE s
    END
  ) AS data
WHERE data.date IS NOT NULL
RETURN c.name AS name, data.date AS date
```

The [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` is used to collect the date-ordered `b` nodes that are shared by the same `a` and `c` node pairs. And the [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function is used to iterate through the ordered `b` nodes to find when the 100 threshold is met.